# How to find a key in a list of permutations?

Tags: python, list, key, permutation

I am making a tic tac toe game and I have run across an issue. I want to make a list that when someone inputs an integer that integer is appended into a list. Once the list contains 3 elements (numbers) I want to generate a list of permutations of those numbers and check it against the 8 winning combinations possible in tic tac toe. However, while I am able to create permutations of the numbers in the list and check the list for the winning combinations the code is not recognizing that the key is in the list. Can you help me figure this out? Here's the code, thanks.

```
player_moves = [1, 3, 2]
for combo in permutations(player_moves, 3):
    player_moves = combo
    print(player_moves)
computer_moves = []
winning_combination = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (1, 5, 9), (3, 6, 9)]

for key in winning_combination:
    for moves in player_moves:
        if moves == key:
            print(str(key) + " was found")
            break
        else:
            print(str(key) + " not found")
```

Comment: The only thing in `player_moves` is the last `combo` you assigned to it. You need to store the permutations is a list or dictionary in order to check them later — or just generate them when you want to compare them to `winning_combination`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the input. How can I store all the permutations as a list or dictionary to check them later?

Comment: Never mind…see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you have to trap all your moves in list:

```
initial_move = [1, 3, 2]
player_moves = []
for combo in itertools.permutations(initial_move, 3):
    player_moves.append(combo)
    print(player_moves)
winning_combination = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (1, 5, 9), (3, 6, 9)]

for key in winning_combination:
    for moves in player_moves:
        if moves == key:
            print(str(key) + " was found")
            break
        else:
            print(str(key) + " not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what the goal is of you're trying to accomplish, but here's a way of doing it that doesn't require storing the permutations of player moves at all—contrary to the suggestion in my comment—because you can just generate them iteratively via `itertools.permutations()` as needed:

```
from itertools import permutations

player_moves = [1, 3, 2]
computer_moves = []
winning_combinations = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9),
                        (1, 5, 9), (3, 6, 9)]

for key in winning_combinations:
    for moves in permutations(player_moves, 3):
        if moves == key:
            print(str(key) + " WAS FOUND")
            break
        else:
            print(str(key) + " not found")
```

Based on your comments, I now suggest you make `winning_combinations` a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a `list` because they provide a way to do very fast membership testing that doesn't require two `for` loops (which means the `break` will halt further searching).

```
from itertools import permutations

winning_combinations = {(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9),
                        (1, 5, 9), (3, 6, 9)}

player_moves = [1, 3, 2]
for moves in permutations(player_moves, 3):
    if moves in winning_combinations:
        print(str(moves) + " is a winning combination")
        break
else:
    print("no permutation of moves was a winning combination")
```

Comment: Thanks. For the tic tac toe game I have each open square assigned a number and when a number is chosen by the player I want to put it in a list. Since there are 8 possible winning combinations in tic tic toe I want to take the list of positions the player has inputted, find all the possible permutations of their positions and compare any of those permutations to the inning combinations list, ergo the key for loops.

Comment: Seems like the `for` loops should be in reverse order. i.e. Check to see if any permutation of a player's moves are a winning combination. It also seems like the checking could quit as soon as one is found.

Comment: Okay, I have ''' break ''' after if the for loop contains the key, however, its simply moves on to the else statement. How would I amend that?

Comment: Well, while you could do it by using a flag to indicate to the outer loop that it should also `break`, it would be even better to not use nested `for` loops in the first place. See update I made to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a quicker (and arguably simpler) mechanism if you turn the played position into a set and check if it is a superset of any of the winning combinations:

```
winning_combination = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 4, 7), 
                       (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (1, 5, 9), (3, 6, 9)]

keys = filter(set(player_moves).issuperset,winning_combination)
print(keys or "no key", "found")
```